# Why gMap does not center the map on coordinates?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Why the following gMap parameters returns a view with the marker close to the bottom side of the view instead of in its center?

Thanks.

```
      <!-- Google Maps -->
            <section class="google-map-container">

            <div id="googlemaps" class="google-map google-map-full" style="padding-bottom:40%"></div>
            <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
            <script src="/assets/scripts/jquery.gmap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('#googlemaps').gMap({
                maptype: 'ROADMAP',
                scrollwheel: false,
                center: '44.51154, 11.28113',
                zoom: 16,
                markers: [
                    {
                        latitude: 44.51154,
                        longitude: 11.28113,
                                          html: 'My company name<br/>Address</br>City<br/>Country',
                        popup: false,
                    }
                ],
            });
            </script>
        </section>
        <!-- Google Maps / End -->
```

EDIT: Updated the code section with also CSS styles.

Comment: What version are you using? And I think you need to set a parameter `center` (not in the marker).

Comment: We are using version 2.1.2

Comment: Not even center helps. We added this line `center: '44.51154, 11.28113',` without succeeding.

Comment: No it is not the `center` parameter sorry, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set to `longitude` and `latitude` in your options in order to get you map to center.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#googlemaps').gMap({
    latitude: 44.51154, // Add this to your options
    longitude: 11.28113, // Add this to your options
    maptype: 'ROADMAP',
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 16,
    markers: [
        {
          latitude: 44.51154,
          longitude: 11.28113,
          html: 'My company name<br/>Address</br>City<br/>Country',
          popup: false,
        }
   ],
});
</script>
```

See documentation: http://gmap.nurtext.de/documentation.html.

Your marker `latitude` and `longitude` is just for placing a marker on that position. The map will not automatically center on that marker as far as I know.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle? According to the documentation it should work that way.

Comment: Edited the code section, now it includes the CSS styles. Can the margin `tag` be the problem?

Comment: Yes that could certainly be a problem. What does it look like when you remove that?